# Where should I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I asked this question here:

[How can I modify this bash script so that the port argument is optional?](https://superuser.com/q/1710245/642458)

On second thought, I wonder whether https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ (I have a Mac) would have been more appropriate. What do you think? If all three sites are equally appropriate, then I guess this is the best one, since currently, it's the one with the most traffic.

Comment: It's fine on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundaries between the various SE sites aren't always cut and dry, and this question could easily be on-topic on several sites, including Super User, Unix and Linux, Ask Different, and potentially even Stack Overflow.

TL;DR - it's fine where it is, and since it was posted it seems like it has already been answered.